# How to import an external javascript library in a typescript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, external

I want to create a small library as an excuse to learn Typescript, but what happens is that I really am not able to import a Javascript library (node-json-equal) to my typescript project. I didn't find a lot on internet that explain clearly how it works, so I bet you to explain me how to solve the problem properly and why is my approach incorrect... well I guess because properly that external library isn't typed.

[Project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPodd.png)

Comment: The image you posted makes it looks more like you're having an issue with another tool. More information about your project would make this easier to diagnose and help with.

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser , thanks for partecipating. 

Basically I want to create a JS library using TS. Its task is to receive a string and, depending on the content of the string, return a specific JSON object.

An important thing to know is that this string-JSON obj relation is 1:1. All the relations are contained in a large JSON (_messages_ in the image), injected from outside though _setMessages()_.

The first step inside _setMessages()_ is to check if the input JSON obj is empty. To check that, I'd like to use an untyped JSON library: _node-json-equal_.

Comment: I know... I could do it manually, but I really want to understand how TS works. At least I was expecting it to work using _require()_, but It didn't. Feel free to ask, if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. It wasn't related with my source code, but my dockerfile. Basically I added package-lock.json that was corrupted, so in the end the module wasn't downloaded. I solved adding the package.json instead.

Answer (score 0):

To work with an external JS library you can either:

**A) Use a typings file**

There are many typings files ready to be used, check out the [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) webpage for a list of ready to be used definition files.

If you cannot find a definition file for your library I highly recommended that you create one yourself. Check out [this guide](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files) for more information about how to create your own definition files.

**B) Declare a variable for your library**

By using the declare keyword you tell the compiler to not check for type safety on that specific variable.

```
declare var nodeJsonEqual: any;
```

If use this approach, you basically turn of the type checking for this variable and it's up to you to make sure that there actually exist a variable named nodeJsonEqual at runtime and that the functions you call have the correct signature.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I actually tried the second method, but it doesn't work. It've put it right after the import statement, but it didn't work. The problem persisted :( What did I do wrong?

Comment: So when you use the declare keyword you tell the compiler that the variable exist "outside the typescript world". So you don't need any import in the typescript file. However it is your job to make sure that the library create a variable called the same as your declared variable

Comment: And what should this library variable contain? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can you write me a code snippet to understand?

Comment: I mean, if I declare a variable and I don't import anything, how can my program understand that I want to use that library? I expect that at least I've to use "require". And by the way, I tried "require" but It didn't work :(